# Generating a random location for text span inside a parent div

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am working on a project where I am generating a word cloud based on data that I am getting from an API. I am trying to find a way to position each word dynamically while also avoiding collisions and preventing them from spilling outside the parent div. To accomplish this I needed the following information:
The size of the text that is rendered
The total space (height and width) for all words
saved indexes of words that have already been rendered.

I was able to accomplish this by positioning each word inside a span and setting the height and width to auto with no margin or padding. I can then use `injectedSpan.clientWidth` to get the width of the element and `injectedSpan.clientHeight` to get the height values. I also discovered that I could use `injectedSpan.getBoundingClientRect()` and get back an object with the following information:

```
x : 0

y : 50

width : 708

height : 0

top : 50

right : 708

bottom : 50

left : 0
```

Once I had this information I thought it would be pretty easy to render the text to unique locations but for some reason there is still a lot of text that is overlapping each other. I wrote a JS Function that checks weather the top and right values are in range of the existing elements and if it is then generate a new unique location. I am not sure if I am missing something obvious. Here is my code so far:  https://jsfiddle.net/amotor/3fuje46q/22/

Answer (score 1):

as your request.

```js
function randomLoc(elm, parent){
  function randomNumber(min, max) {  
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
  }  
  let scH = parent.offsetHeight;
  let scW = parent.offsetWidth;
  
  elm.setAttribute("style", 'left: '+randomNumber(0, scW)+'px; top:'+randomNumber(0, scH)+'px;');
}
randomLoc(
document.getElementById('testElm'),
document.getElementById('parent')
);
```

```css
#parent{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:yellow;
}
#testElm{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <button id="testElm">test</button
</div>
```